# iphone: (audio) posting message to kill mediaserverd

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, core-audio

I'm playing several sounds using: [AudioServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(aSystemSoundID);`

When I test the project on an *iPhone 3G* attached to the machine I get this message:

```
> 2010-09-16 17:29:29.672
> myProject[6528:6def] [17:29:29.672
> <0x85d400>] PlaySound posting message
> to kill mediaserverd (5958) [Switching
> to thread 13059]
```

and / or:

```
> 2010-09-16 17:30:28.316
> myProject[6528:6def] [17:30:28.316
> <0x85d400>] AudioQueueNew posting
> message to kill mediaserverd (0)
> Error: AudioQueueNewInput failed
> (0x10004003)
```

Any idea why?

Thanks.

BTW, on the simulator everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this post, which sounds sort of similar.  Is trying this an option?

[AudioQueueStart posting message to kill mediaserverd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952469/audioqueuestart-posting-message-to-kill-mediaserverd)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same message when trying to set the audio category (I'm using Audio Units).  A reboot of the iPad fixed it for me.