# AudioQueuePrime posting message to kill mediaserverd (20)

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

In my application i am having 25 images, each image has corresponding music. I am playing the music when clicking on the image using avaudioplayer. But when i am clicking on all the images very fastly i am getting a error in console **AudioQueuePrime posting message to kill mediaserverd (20)** I am not able to fine why i am getting.

Plase help me

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone: (audio) posting message to kill mediaserverd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762675/iphone-audio-posting-message-to-kill-mediaserverd)