# AudioQueueStart posting message to kill mediaserverd

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have a piano application. It's working fine, with a little error. If I play several keys at the same time very fast, the sounds disappears for a couple of seconds, and receive the following message in the console

> AudioQueueStart posting message to kill mediaserverd

Here is the relevant code:

```
-(IBAction)playNoteFromKeyTouch:(id) sender{

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(playNote:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Piano.mf.%@",[sender currentTitle]]];

}

-(void)playNote:(NSString *) note{
    NSError *err;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:note ofType:@"aiff"];
    AVAudioPlayer *p = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&err];
    p.delegate = self;
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
    }else{
        [p prepareToPlay];
        [p play];
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [player release];
}
```

I have tested with Instruments and I don't have any memory leak. If somebody could have an idea to avoid this error it would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone: (audio) posting message to kill mediaserverd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762675/iphone-audio-posting-message-to-kill-mediaserverd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the issue using SoundBankPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer. [SoundBanker info](http://www.hollance.com/2011/02/soundbankplayer-using-openal-to-play-musical-instruments-in-your-ios-app/).

Answer (score 3):

I suffer from a similar issue.

I spent ages trying to solve the issue, and I think my particular issue takes place when:

1. I'm in an AudioCategory that doesn't allow sound to play while the mute switch is on.
2. I start to play a sound (I actually don't do this in the app, but this is how I can reproduce reliably).
3. With the sound still playing, I switch to another AudioCategory that doesn't allow sound to play while the mute switch is on.

From this point onwards, I get 'posting message to kill mediaserverd' from what looks like various points in calls in the AudioSession API. The app hangs, the device hangs, and I struggle to get the device back to a normal running state.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this message](https://devforums.apple.com/message/583670#583670) **it's the device's mute switch.**

> It turns out that having the iPad muted via the device's physical switch was
>   causing the problem with my app.  As long as the button is not
>   switched on the problem does not occur.

Sheesh. How to programmatically override?